# Wordpress multisite user edit permission error

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on wordpress multisite.

When a user creates new site he is given the role of an administrator.He has capabilities of

1. 'edit-user',
2. 'manage_network_users',
3. 'edit_users','promote_users'.

But the user gets permission error when he tries to edit another user within the same site.

But if i comment the line that says :

```
`if(!current_user_can('edit_user', $userid))` in user-edit.php line around 148 and 100
```

it works.But the user role cannot be changed.

The funny thing is that that the user has the capability 'edit_user', I have checked it a lot of of times.

What can be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

i found a link http://thereforei.am/2011/03/15/how-to-allow-administrators-to-edit-users-in-a-wordpress-network/#comment-6855 that has the perfect answer for this. Apparently the blocking is done by the capabilities.php not user-edit.php.Thanks to this site my problem is solved.